# Unsuccessful Updating table with PHP using Update table Set

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table `buildtracker` connected to a form. I am attempting to edit the data in a particular row and therefore `Update` the row.

The table consists of these columns:  ID *key*, EnteredBy, INI

```
$user = 'root';
$pass = '';
$db = 'cl_db';
$conn = new mysqli('localhost', $user, $pass, $db) or die("Something bad happened.");

$rowID = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['ID']);
$enteredBy    = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['enteredBy']); 
$ini   = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['ini']);

$query   = "UPDATE buildtracker SET 
          EnteredBy = '$enteredBy', INI = '$ini'
          WHERE ID = '$rowID' ";

$success = $conn->query($query); //insertion above ^ is the column names

if (!$success) {
    die("Couldn't enter data: ".$conn->error);
    }
return $query;
```

I'm receiving no new data or updates on the table. What can I do differently to improve upon this?

Thanks!

Comment: Feeling confused, your `TABLE` is *truncated* ?

Comment: Is `$success` trueish or false?

Comment: show your declaration of the connection variable `$conn`

Comment: also, your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks

Comment: I removed the truncated to avoid confusion. All I mean is that there are more columns - didn't feel it necessary for the nature of the question to sort through more code if unrelated

Comment: Added conn variable. And not sure what you mean @Adder

Comment: @BR89 he asked if `$success` equals to `true` (I use to say *truthy* or *falsy*)

Comment: I mean do you get any error messages, or is everything working but just the entry in the db doesn't change? Did you try printing the query to see if anything is odd about it?

Comment: Gotcha. Not receiving any errors. Nothing seems odd as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know in what context this code is, in your application.

But is is [highly] recommended to use prepared statements for protection against any SQL injection attacks, especially direct data from $_POST is used (can be sanitized).

Checking whether query is executed or not in prepared statements is via [$stmt->execute()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php).

```
$user = 'root';
$pass = '';
$db = 'cl_db';
$conn = new mysqli('localhost', $user, $pass, $db) or die("Something bad happened.");
$prepare_query = "UPDATE buildtracker SET EnteredBy=?, INI=? WHERE ID=?";
$success = $conn->query($prepare_query); //insertion above ^ is the column names
if ($stmt = $conn->prepare($query)) {

    // Possible data sanitation can be done below
    $rowID = ($_POST['ID']);
    $enteredBy = ($_POST['enteredBy']); 
    $ini = ($_POST['ini']);

    // bind parameters
    $stmt->bind_param('ssi', $enteredBy, $ini, $rowID);

    // CHECKING is here: execute query (or die)
    // Can check also for ($stmt->affected_rows > 0)
    if (!$stmt->execute()){
        die("Couldn't enter data: ".$conn->error);
    }

    return $query;
}
```

And using [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead of [`MySQLi`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) would probably be better recommended.

Answer (score 0):

As all errors that I create - this was a result of the declaration of my `$rowID` not pointing the correct html element.

original

```
$rowID   = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['ID']); // ID is the COLUMN NAME
```

Working

```
$rowID   = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['rowID']); //rowID is the DOM element name
```

Thank you for your comments and answers.

Going to look into implementing Hossam's safer version of preventing injections. I appreciate you all :)